It is possible to estimate the height of an explosion by its looks?
There's various social media postings (e.g. on reddit or on Twitter) saying this is what an exoatmospheric intercept (by an Arrow) missile looks like (I took 4 frames from the video, in case you don't want to watch it as such):

The claim seems somewhat plausible in that explosives don't need external oxygen to go off.
Can the height of an explosion be estimated by the looks of it, i.e. do violet-ball explosion have to be exoatmospheric?
(I'm slithgly skeptical on the exo-part because one can see a bright small dot moving in the sky before the explosion.)

The missiles used by Iran are not exoatmospheric.

@JonCuster: I guess that would be a good answer on Skeptics. [I might ask it there if it's off topic here.] I'm wondering what the actual height might be though, of what we're seeing, even in a wide-ish range.

As it turns out, at https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-68811273 there is a quote that suggests one may have been exoatmospheric. Interesting

The answer to your question might depend very much on what, exactly, is exploding.
